# How to find value (true or false) from AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, boolean

I have written a script register user. And in the last step I need value true or false from a function to find that email is already existed or not.

```
function do_register(user_email){

    if (!isemailexist(user_email))  {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="email is already exist, please change!!";
    document.regForm.user_email.focus()
    return false;
    } 

if (user_email=="") {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="email is emphy!!";
    document.regForm.user_email.focus()
    return false;
    } 

if(document.regForm.user_name.value!=""){ process_register();} } 

function isemailexist ()

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function () {

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){

    var str=xmlHttp.responseText;
    var res=JSON.parse(str);

    if (res[0]=="no"){  
    return false;
    }
    }
    haha=xmlHttp.onreadystatechange.test(res[0]); ///I used test(); methode  in order to find value true or false

    }
```

I have tried alot but none of them could give me true or fals !

I have updated my script above, I hope it´s better. Some more code:

PHP CODE

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){ //  email is already exist
     $phpArray = array("no","Erroremail is aleady exist");
     echo json_encode($phpArray);
 }
```

Comment: OK, When sql said this email is already in database, I separate the result to be 2 strings "no" and "Erroremail is aleady exist"

Then this will return respond to ajax via json.
After that I want to get a true or false value if this could be process to register or not.

in other word, If email is already exist user can not be registed.Ul til he fill out the email that does not exist in database

Comment: Yeah I got that after a while. Check my answer. You don't really need JSON on this one, you're just checking the database, and if the email already exists, you're just going to return it false. If it doesn't, return true.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things bit too complicated. There's no need of making an array when the response is simply false, as you're already telling the user that the email already exists.

Instead of doing

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){ //  email is already exist
     $phpArray = array("no","Erroremail is aleady exist");
     echo json_encode($phpArray);
}
```

Just do this in your server side.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){ //  email is already exist
     return false;
}
```

---

As you're no longer using an array, your response changes, and you need to adjust your code a little bit. Remove `[0]` from `res[0]`.

---

Then your server response will be false, so change

```
if (res[0]=="no"){  
    return false;
}
```

to

```
if (res==false){  
    return false;
}
else{
//continue...
}
```

Comment: Yeahhh thanks Christian: I never thought that could be so easy like this. I did it too complicated.
I change the php to 
 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

  return false;

.But the problem is solv ...cheeers!!

Comment: @PoramatFin In future projects, try to get rid of the **mysql_()** extension, instead you should be using PDO on mysql connections, as it's much more safer, and more logical after you get used to it. SO itself has a pretty good quick and dirty reference of PDO, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info. Remember, **never trust user input**, always validate it **server-side**. Here's an example what could and will happen if you do not sanitize your inputs. http://littlebobbytables.com/. Glad I helped!

Comment: Thanks Christian, I haven´t heard about this before..I will read it. sound interestin!!

Comment: Hey, Christian...After I test it many times now...seem to be something wrong here:
In the beginning when I test your script with the same email I have in database and I got the result I want...but when I put the other email which´s not in database....it return the same result (false)
What should I do now ?

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your mysql query. @PoramatFin

Comment: No, I don´t think so. I have test it everything work fine in mysql.
But another thing I found: after I remove ajax method from function isemailexist () and just put return true or return false instead, Everything work like amazing ! That means ajax can not give value true or false inside. 

But my problem is, if I can not use ajax, so I could not validate if email is already exist or not.

Comment: Then it's a problem with your script, if you would be using a library, like jQuery, ajax would be much easier, and more cross-browser. But check my updated answer. @PoramatFin

Comment: Hi, Christian, I have tried it last night nothing work!
I have also change this xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true) to xmlHttp.open("GET",url,false) it work ! But after that the script won´t validate other thing,: after the data said this email is available...and it submit it self at once, Annd ignore the other validation lines still remain to be validated.

Comment: Now I decided to do all thing from php to turn data to ajax. ANd it work. But not as quick as it does from pure javascript. The only problem is inside javascript I can not get value true or false correctly, that´s why the form could not be validated completely. Because I do it from 2 separate language (validate the form in javascript  and validate the  user is exist from php via ajax.) 

I tried to find the way to get the true or false value inside javascript, but it seem like it´s unable to do it via ajax.

Comment: Why I know ? Because after I take the function out side ajax and have a simple test, I could get the value true or false corectly.

But now I have to say goodbye for this...So tired of the crazy script.


But thanks....